# In PostgreSQL, how do you insert date you've extracted into a query?

Tags: postgresql

So i am supposed to find purchases made by customers holding visa credit card on New Year's Day. The table has a datetime field; I can extract the date  from it but how do I have it in the WHERE Clause?

```
SELECT cs.name , DATE(t.datetime) AS new_year
FROM customers cs, credit_cards cc, transactions t
WHERE t.number = cc.number
AND cc.type ='visa'
AND t.amount NOTNULL 
AND new_year = '2019-01-01';
```

above query shows type(new_year) does not exist

Comment: column aliases cannot be used in the `WHERE` clause.  You need to use the actual expression, i.e. `...AND DATE(t.datetime) = '2019-01-01`'

Comment: ah i see! Thank you for the information! It works now; would having SELECT(DATE(t.datetime) = ... ) vs just DATE(t.datetime) = .... make any difference?

When I run it, the row output is the same number  but the order changes

Comment: That would not necessary make the order different.  In a RDB rows are unordered and the DBMS is free to return rows on any order. If you want to ensure rows return  in the same order then you must use the `order by` clause - there is simple NO other way to ensure order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same function you've used in the `SELECT` part also in the `WHERE` part: `WHERE DATE(t.datetime) = '2019-01-01'`